# my npm commands aren't working, npm is bugging?

Tags: node.js, npm

```
C:\Users\jason\OneDrive\Documents\Web-Dev-Projects\pinterest-clone>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\jason\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v14.17.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jason\OneDrive\Documents\Web-Dev-Projects\pinterest-clone\npm-debug.log
```

I am getting this really annoying error that doesn't even tell me what's wrong with npm. I tried deleting and installing node.js again and running the command npm install but I would still get the error. I even tried running a command to use the latest version of npm and it still wouldn't work (npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade & npm-windows-upgrade).

It seems like npm is just being very buggy and doesn't want to work. Help please.

Comment: Considering npm's current version is 7.x, 3.10.10 isn't very new.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this very similar issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1712), you really shouldn't be using npm 3.x with Node 14.

You might want to uninstall Node, ensure there are no traces of Node or npm on your system, then reinstall Node 14 or 16.

They automatically install newer versions of npm (6 or newer).

Also, [the `npm-windows-upgrade` package you mention](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade) hasn't been updated in 3 years. Maybe don't use it?

Comment: i did all that and it still saids npm version 3.10.10

Comment: Then you didn't get rid of all traces of npm on your system. Try again. Search for npm-related files on your system if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely not running the latest version of the tools. NPM is in v7 and Node.js is in v16. Uninstall what you have currently installed, and download the latest version (make sure to choose Current not LTS) to install the latest version. [Here](https://nodejs.org/) is the link

Comment: i did all that and it still saids npm version 3.10.10

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch to a package manager specifically for managing different versions of Node + NPM side-by-side on your machine, which saves you the hassle of having to have 1 global installation that just "has to work" for all your projects.

Linux has `nvm` (node version manager). Since you're on Windows, you might want to check out the Windows-"fork": https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows.

It should prevent incompatible versions of node and npm being installed together.